# php adding one more backslash

Tags: php, backslash

What i'm trying to do is echo the input of the user which is the value of the get variable named `snm`.
The problem is `php` is for some reason adding an extra backslash, how can i stop this?
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$string = $_GET['snm'];
echo $string;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When i enter `\` into the get variable named `snm` the echo i get is `\\` instead of `\` which is what i want.

Answer (score 1):

You have Magic Quotes turned on.  You should turn that off.

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php